# Remove contents in a file

Tags: linux, sed

I want to remove all city names and output it to a file called cities in a single command.
[image]

**Would I use**

```
sed s/^\w+-\w+-//
```

How would I do it since I don't have a viable way of determining if something is a city or not

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add `Chicago-Bears-NFC` and `Washington-Football-Team-NFC` to your sample input (see https://www.nfl.com/teams/) and add the expected output for the sample input and explain the rules you'd apply to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the city, extract the team name and conference:

```bsh
grep -Eo '[^-]+-[^-]+$' <<INPUT
New-England-Patriots-AFC
Dallas-Cowboys-NFC
INPUT
```

outputs

```
Patriots-AFC
Cowboys-NFC
```

This method breaks when the team name is multi-word: "Washington-Football-Team-NFC". In that case, you'll have to fix the input to make the ambiguities go away at the source.

Comment: What does the "^" represent? @glennj

Comment: `[^-]` is a "bracket expression". Here, it means "any character that is NOT a hyphen"